# How to fill a c# windows form listview with datas from 2 tables?

Tags: c#, sql, listview

I'm doing a "load" button to load up all datas from a SQL database, to put them in a listview.

```
if(lstEnsemble.Items.Count == 0)
{
    MySqlConnection connexion = OpenConnection();
    MySqlCommand reqRemplissageClient = new MySqlCommand("select * from client order by idClient ASC;", connexion);
    MySqlCommand reqRemplissagePanne = new MySqlCommand("select * from Panne order by idClient ASC;", connexion);

    MySqlDataReader resultatClient = reqRemplissageClient.ExecuteReader();
    MySqlDataReader resultatPanne = reqRemplissageClient.ExecuteReader();

    while (resultatClient.Read() && resultatPanne.Read())
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(resultatClient["nomCli"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(resultatClient["prenomCli"].ToString());
        if (resultatClient["idClient"] == resultatPanne["idClient"])
        {
            item.SubItems.Add(resultatPanne["appareil"].ToString());
        }
        item.SubItems.Add(resultatClient["villeCli"] + " " + resultatClient["cpCli"] + " " + resultatClient["rueCli"]);
        item.SubItems.Add(resultatClient["telCli"].ToString());
        if (resultatClient["idClient"] == resultatPanne["idClient"])
        {
            item.SubItems.Add(resultatPanne["description"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(resultatPanne["dateEntree"].ToString());
        }
        item.SubItems.Add(resultatClient["mailCli"].ToString());
        lstEnsemble.Items.Add(item);
    }

    CloseConnection(connexion);
}
```

This does not work, obviously, but I can't manage to find another way to do this.
I tried to do both of requests separately, but again I'm missing the logic to this.

Comment: Do you presume/_hope_ that `idClient` matches exactly in both tables? Or is it possible and valid that you combine the rows with unequal `idClient` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question it's not fully clear what kind of data you are working with. It seems your presuming (or better *hoping*) that the `idClient` values match exactly in both tables.

I presume that you actually want to do a `JOIN`. If this is not true, I will delete this post again.

So you should do only one query using a `JOIN`:

```
if(lstEnsemble.Items.Count == 0)
{
    string sql = @"SELECT nomCli, prenomCli, appareil, villeCli, rueCli,
                   cpCli, telCli, description, dateEntree, mailCli
                   FROM client LEFT JOIN Panne ON (client.idClient = Panne.idClient)";

    MySqlConnection connexion = OpenConnection();
    MySqlCommand request = new MySqlCommand(sql, connexion);

    MySqlDataReader resultat = requestExecuteReader();
    while (resultat.Read())
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(resultat["nomCli"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(resultat["prenomCli"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(resultat["appareil"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(resultat["villeCli"] + " " + resultat["cpCli"] + " " + resultat["rueCli"]);
        item.SubItems.Add(resultat["telCli"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(resultat["description"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(resultat["dateEntree"].ToString());
        item.SubItems.Add(resultat["mailCli"].ToString());
        lstEnsemble.Items.Add(item);
    }

    CloseConnection(connexion);
}
```

But you should be aware that for rows in `client` with no matching rows in `Panne` there will be `null` values in the results. So you need to check for them first using `resultat.IsDbNull()` on the column index (position in sql query).
Alternativly you may use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN` to get only rows that exist in both tables.

Comment: I feel retarded. I totally had forgotten that you can join tables. Thanks a lot for your fast answer ! have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You should change a few things, then it becomes pretty easy.

1. Make a single SQL Query. Just JOIN your tables together and SELECT what you need.
2. Separate the Database access from filling your listview. Put your result in an array or datatable.
3. With your data available you can easily bind it or iterate through it to generate ListViewItems.

Comment: Thanks too, i had forgotten that you can join tables... shame on me